# Tensorflow Loss gets Nan because of Lp-Norm as Custom Layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nan, loss, norm

Tensorflow Loss gets Nan because of Lp-Norm as Custom Layer using following Code:

```
class CLayerPowerDensity(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CLayerPowerDensity, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.lp = self.add_weight(name='lp_norm',
                                 shape=(1,),
                                 initializer='ones',
                                 trainable=False)
        super(CLayerPowerDensity, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        p = (self.lp**2) + 1 

        return K.pow(K.pow(K.abs(inputs[0]), p) + (K.pow(K.abs(inputs[1]), p)), (1/p))
```

Does anybody knows why i get nan in Loss? and how to solve the problem....

if i use `return K.sqrt(((inputs[0] ** 2) + (inputs[1] ** 2)))`everything works fine. Even with the above return-value. But if i turn the weight "lp-norm" to true, my loss gets nan

Comment: You can debug by printing every input and output and check if either one of these values contains NaN. And when you found out try breaking down with operation is creating the nan.

Comment: okay i did and it is the operation (1/p)... the strange thing about it is, that for the first Epoch p = 2 (==same value for trainable = false) so at least it should be one epoch without nan but i get nan at the beginning of the first epoch by simply turning trainable to true...